# An Activity of Binary to Decimal in any base by integrating dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x

We have an activity in coding and it seems that my interpretation of this long instruction is not correct. Can you help me with my code by modifying or overhauling it? I am a Highschool student. Thank You.

THE INSTRUCTION:

In Chapter 4, we developed an algorithm for converting from binary to decimal. You can generalize this algorithm to work for a representation in any base. Instead of using a power of 2, you will write a program that converts any base between 2 and 16. Recall that for numbers 10 - 15 we use letters A - F.

> In convert.py, define a function named repToDecimal that expects two arguments, a string, and an integer. The second argument should be the base. For example, repToDecimal("10", 8) returns 8, whereas repToDecimal("10", 16) returns 16.

> The function should use a lookup table to find the value of any digit. Make sure that this table (it is actually a dictionary) is initialized before the function is defined.

> For its keys, use the 10 decimal digits (all strings) and the letters A . . >F (all uppercase). The value stored with each key should be the integer that the digit represents. (The letter A associates with the integer value 10, and so on.)

> The main loop of the function should convert each digit to uppercase, look up its value in the table, and use this value in the computation.
> A main function that tests the conversion function with numbers in several bases has been provided.

[image: This is the picture]

```
conversionLibrary = {"0":0, "1":1, "2":2, "3":3, "4":4, "5":5, "6":6, "7":7, "8":8, "9":9, "A":10, "B":10, "C":11, "D":13, "E":14, "F":15}

n = input("Enter a number you want changed to base 10: ")

fromBase = int(input("Enter a the base from which you want changed: "))

n = n.upper()

def repToDecimal(n, fromBase):
    toNumber = 0
    power = 0
    for i in range((len(n)),0, -1):
        toNumber += conversionLibrary[n[i-1]] * (int(fromBase) ** power)
        power += 1
        return(toNumber)

def main():
    print(repToDecimal('10', 10))
    print(repToDecimal('10', 8))
    print(repToDecimal('10', 2))
    print(repToDecimal('10', 16))

main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my answer. I got 100 points.

```
dict={'0':0,'1':1,'2':2,'3':3,'4':4,'5':5,'6':6,'7':7,'8':8,'9':9,'A':10,'B':11,'C':12,'D':13,'E':14,'F':15}
def repToDecimal(str,base):
    result = 0
#initializing a dictionary
    for i in str:
        n = dict[i]
        result = base * result + n
    return result
#calling the method and displaying the result
print(repToDecimal('10',10))
print(repToDecimal('10',8))
print(repToDecimal('10',2))
print(repToDecimal('10',16))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).